# PyQt5, first row filter, columns with integers

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyqt5, integer

I have an application in which after clicking on a button will appear a new window with dataframe displayed. By clicking on a header I can filter the table. The problem is that the filter works only with string values. If there are in the columns integers, the application will crash. Is there any possibility how to filter columns with integers?

Bellow is the code for the second window:

```
class pandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
    QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self._df = df.copy()
    self.colors = dict()

def toDataFrame(self):
    return self._df.copy()

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
        try:
            return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
        except (IndexError,):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
    elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
        try:
            return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
        except (IndexError,):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

    if index.isValid():
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            return str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

def setData(self, index, value, role):
    row = self._df.index[index.row()]
    col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
    if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
        value = value.toPyObject()
    else:
        dtype = self._df[col].dtype
        if dtype != object:
            value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
    self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
    return True

def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    return len(self._df.index)

def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    return len(self._df.columns)

def sort(self, column, order):
    colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
    self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
    self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending=order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
    self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    self.layoutChanged.emit()

def change_color(self, row, column, color):
    ix = self.index(row, column)
    self.colors[(row, column)] = color
    self.dataChanged.emit(ix, ix, (Qt.BackgroundRole,))
```

Bellow is a code for setting the filters:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
    filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
    filterString = QtCore.QRegExp("",
                                  QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                  QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                  )

    self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
    self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
    stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
    filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
    filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(stringAction,
                                  QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive,
                                  QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString
                                  )

    self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
    self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):

    self.logicalIndex = logicalIndex
    self.menuValues = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
    self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)

    valuesUnique = self.model._df.iloc[:, self.logicalIndex].unique()

    actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
    actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
    self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
    self.menuValues.addSeparator()
    for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):
        if actionName == "":
            continue
        action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)
        action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.menuValues.addAction(action)
    self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)
    headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
    posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
    posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

    self.menuValues.setStyleSheet("QMenu { menu-scrollable: 1; }")
    self.menuValues.setMaximumHeight(600)
    self.menuValues.popup(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))
    self.menuValues.move(posX, posY)

    self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))
```

Bellow is the code which is activated by clicking on the button. It opens the second window:

```
def newWindow(self, table):

    self.model = pandasModel(table)
    self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
    self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
    self.view.resize(1500, 600)
    self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
    self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)
    self.view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    self.view.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].